# How to grant persistable uri permission to a Uri received from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider

On my app I have a function to attach files and contacts and other things.

I use an Intent to pick multiple files from a picker.

When I use `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`... I can pick files from many places like Google Photos, or Music Apps, or Contacts. But the permission to the result Uri expires when I live the activity...

When I use `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`... I don´t have any problem with permissions ussing `takePersistableUriPermission` but I lose to pick files from Google Photos, Music Apps, and Contacts...

**So is there a way to grant persistable uri permission to a Uri received from `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or that is exclusive to `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`?**

Comment: I haven't found a way. Have you?